# Error in implementing Inheritance in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var old = {name:'abc',id:'3'};
new = Object.create(old);
alert(new.name);
```

I am trying to run this simple example but it is not working. What can be wrong?

**EDIT**: I made a mistake taking reserved keyword as a variable name, now please dont kill me for that. Happens.

The following makes sense :

```
var parent = {name:'abc',id:'3'};
child= Object.create(parent );
child(new.name);
```

For any other user landing here searching for Inheritance in Javascript then in Javascript Inheritance is achieved by linking a object with other as shown above. When you use a variable, javascript engine would search for that variable in current object and if it does not find it, It will look into the linked object and get value from there.

Thanks. Cheers!!

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript. Change it to something else. Also, unless specified somewhere else, you'd need `var` in front of a new variable.

Comment: In almost all lenguages, 'new' is a reserved keyword. Don't you even see the console?

Comment: @AnantDabhi—not everyone uses an editor that highlights keywords in blue (or at all). Please don't reference [*w3schools*](http://www.w3fools.com), the authoritative reference is [*ECMA-262*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-reserved-words) and [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_keywords_as_of_ECMAScript_6) for examples.

Comment: @MauroBilotti Sorry, my bad. I was trying the code from a javascript playground(JSFiddle) so when seeing console was not able to figure out specific error as there were already many of them.

Comment: @RobG Exactly Rob, thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new` is a keyword.

You need to update from

```
new = Object.create(old);
alert(new.name);
```

to

```
var x = Object.create(old);
alert(x.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is working.

```
var old = {name:'abc',id:'3'};
var obj = Object.create(old);
alert(obj.name);
```